# Error in implementing WebSocket in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, socket.io, google-kubernetes-engine

We are trying to implement WebSocket in Kubernetes by following steps given in GCP document "https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#support_for_websocket"  & "https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service"  . but we are getting "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502”.

```
Error Message : “WebSocket connection to 'wss://..../backend-channeladaptor-web/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502”.
```

I have also attached  Files created for gke implementation:

1. Backend-channeladaptor-web.yaml

   - Deployment content
   - Service content
   - Backendconfig content
2. Converse-ingress.yaml (It has details of other services as well you can ignore that except backend-channeladaptor-web).

Converse-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: converse-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: $Static-Ip-Name
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: $SSL-certificate
  rules:
  - host: $HostName
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-chat-client
          servicePort: 3040
      - path: /socket-io/*
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-channeladaptor-engineerportal
          servicePort: 11009          
      - path: /login/*
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-engineeringportal
          servicePort: 3021
      - path: /frontend-engineeringportal/*
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-engineeringportal
          servicePort: 3021
      - path: /backend-channeladaptor-web/*
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-channeladaptor-web
          servicePort: 11006
```

Backend-channeladaptor-web.yaml

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: backend-channeladaptor-web-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 3600
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 3600

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-channeladaptor-web
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"8081":"backend-channeladaptor-web-backendconfig"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 11006
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30078
      name: http
  selector:
    app: backend-channeladaptor-web

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-channeladaptor-web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-channeladaptor-web
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-channeladaptor-web
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/acn-careful-granite-240620/backend-channeladaptor-web:0.2
          name: backend-channeladaptor-web
          ports:
           - name: http
             containerPort: 11006
             hostPort: 11006
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: dev
```

I expect the response status code 101 but getting 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Are you getting 502 **after** the https load balancer is up?

Comment: @yyyyahir we added healthcheck in this service and that is running fine i.e.we are getting status code 200 , but when we hit webSocket call it giving 502 Bad Gateway.
Yes https load balancer is up and running fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ingress has the URI `/backend-channeladaptor-web/*` pointed to the Service `backend-channeladaptor-web` and is expecting the Service to be listening in `11006`. However, the NodePort configuration is listening in `8081`.

The confusion might come from the `targetPort` directive, pointing to `11006` in the actual backend (the Deployment).

This is causing 502's, meaning that althought you're reaching an intermediary (the load balancer in your case), it is unable to reach the backend (the Deployment, served by the NodePort Service).

You can change the ingress definition to point to `8081` instead, matching the current NodePort configuration.

Comment: 1. i tried to change "NodePort configuration to listen 11006" but same issue .


            2. i am able to access health check of all services including above one only websocket call is failed

Comment: Health checks are independent from the `Service` allowing requests to your `Deployment`. [Have you tried](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-running-pods) `run`ning a pod within the cluster and reaching the WS? Or `attach`ing directly to the network space in the pods to see if everything is actually running well there?